Finding a bound on $y_t$ provided that $\dot y_t \leq \alpha (-c-y_t)$
I want to analyze the following differential inequality, where $c \geq 0$, $\alpha \in [0,1]$, and $y_0 = 1$.
$\dot y_t \leq \alpha (-c-y_t)$
It is easy to compute the solution if we had an equality: $\dot y_t = \alpha (-c-y_t)$. In that case, the solution would be:
\begin{align}
y_t = - c + (1+c) \exp(-\alpha t)
\end{align}
But is it possible to say anything about the inequality? For example, can we say $y_t \geq -c + (1+c) \exp(-\alpha t)$?

Yes, just flip the direction of inequality, this is Gronwall inequality. You can see this by $(e^{\alpha t} y )' = e^{\alpha t}(y' + \alpha y) \le -c \alpha e^{\alpha t}$ and integrate on both sides.
